# Image edit not working using PHP and Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

Image Editor that not work with option to change the image size, cropping, rotating and  adjust contact of images.
How to implete image editor options with customizable using javascript or jquery.

Need only this future like crop, resize, adjust with undo and redo options.

```
<div>
  <img id="image" src="picture.jpg">
</div>

const image = document.getElementById('image');
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);
    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) may meet your requirements.

Comment: Resize option is not there in cropperjs.

Comment: try its demo: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/ , you can resize the image by drag, or input the width/height you want

Comment: It's not sutted for the requirement